# Is it possible to derive the rules of set theory as transfers from the pure finite set world, and can we extend this further?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axioms

Informally the idea of this question is about whether the rules of set theory can be derived as a transfer of some rules from the hereditarily finite set realm, and whether this transfer principle itself can be coined for notions other than the "finite" notion?

The principle I want to negotiate is: "if $\phi$ is a property that is definable by a formula in the language of set theory that is strictly shorter than the shortest parameter free formula in that language that can define 'finiteness', then if $\phi$ is CLOSED on the the hereditarily finite set world, then it can be generalized over the whole realm of sets"!

The crude informal idea is that if a property that cannot mention finiteness generalizes over the whole hereditarily finite set realm, then it can go beyond it.

To formally capture that, I'll work up in a class theory, so we define "set" as an element of a class, the language of the theory is mono-sorted first order logic with identity and membership, we stipulate axioms of:

1. Extensionality: as in ZF
2. Class comprehension schema: $\forall x_1,..,x_n\ \exists x \ [x=\{y|set(y) \wedge \phi(y,x_1,..,x_n)\}]  $
3. The empty class is a set
4. Singletons: $\forall x [ set(x) \to set(\{x\})]$
5. Boolean Union: $\forall x,y [set(x) \wedge set(y) \to set (x \cup y)]$

Define: $$ fin(A) \iff \forall  K [\exists o (o \in K \wedge \neg \exists m (m \in o)) \wedge \forall  x (x \in A \to \exists y (y \in K \wedge x \in y \wedge \forall  z (z \in y \to z=x)))  \wedge \\
\forall  a \forall b (a \in K \wedge b \in K \to \exists c (c \in K \wedge \forall  d (d \in c\leftrightarrow d \in a \lor d \in b ))) \\ \to A \in K]$$

In English: $A$ is finite if and only if it is an element of every class $K$ that contains the empty set among its elements, is closed under Boolean union and that has the singletons of all elements of $A$ among its elements.

"I think this is along the shortest way to define "finite set" in this axiomatic theory whose language is first order logic with membership and equality using the customary four logical connectives.

Perhaps the above formula can be shortened further, or perhaps there is another shorter parameter free formulation of "x is a finite set" in the language of set theory, however for the sake of presentation here we'll take this formula to be the shortest formula defining finiteness.

6. $ \forall x (x \text{ is hereditarily finite } \to set(x))$

Where "x is hereditarily finite" is defined as the transitive closure class of x being finite [Another definition is that x is finite and every element of the transitive closure of x is finite also].

We shall denote the class of all sets by $V$, and the class of all hereditarily fintie sets by $HF$

7. $HF \in V$
8. **The principle of Transfer from the pure finite world:** if $\phi(y,x)$ is a formula shorter than any formula defining finiteness, in which only symbols  $``y,x"$ occur free, and those only occur free, then:

$\forall x [x \in HF \to \forall y (\phi(y,x) \to y \in HF)] \to \forall x \in V [ \forall y (\phi(y,x) \to y \in V)]$

Now it is clear that all axioms of Union, Power and Separation over sets are derivable from the above transfer principle, and so $ZC$ is interpretable here. Actaully *IF* we restrict $\phi$ to have no more than three atomic subformulas, so the principle would be written as:

8'. **The principle of *ternary* Transfer from the pure finite world:** if $\phi(y,x)$ is a formula having no more than *three* occurrences of atomic formulas in it, in which only symbols  $``y,x"$ occur free, and those only occur free, then:

$\forall x [x \in HF \to \forall y (\phi(y,x) \to y \in HF)] \to \forall x \in V  
[ \forall y (\phi(y,x) \to y \in V)]$

*THEN* this would still be enough to interpret the whole of $ZC$! Moreover I think that the theory with this ternary version of the transfer principle can be proven to be ***consistent*** relative to $ZFC$.

Replacement is not interpretable by the above two principles. Yet, a minor modification of this principle might succeed in proving replacement over sets, this can be done by changing the closure property to involve only subsets of $HF$, what I call as "proximity closure over HF", so to restate that:

8".**The principle of Transfer from proximity of the pure finite world:** if $\phi(y,x)$ is a formula shorter than any formula defining finiteness, in which only symbols  $``y,x"$ occur free, and those only occur free, then:

$\forall x [x \in HF \to \forall y \subseteq HF (\phi(y,x) \to y \in HF)] \to \forall x \in V [ \forall y (\phi(y,x) \to y \in V)]$

That replacement is provable can be shown from examining the following formula whose length is shorter than any formula defining finiteness.

$\exists F [\forall  m (m \in F \to \exists a,b (a \in A \wedge b \in B \wedge a \in m \wedge b \in m))
\wedge \\ \forall  m,n (m \in F \wedge n \in F \wedge \exists k(k \in m \wedge k \in n) \to n=m) \wedge \\ \forall b (b \in B \to \exists m (m \in F \wedge b \in m))]$

Now if $A$ is hereditarily finite and $B$ is a subset of $HF$ that fulfills the above formula, then $B$ is hereditarily finite, this mean that the property defined by the above formula is "proximity closed over the hereditarily finite world"

I don't have any proof of consistency of these principles, but if there is no clear inconsistency of those relative to $ZF$ or $MK$ or some extension of those, then could it be possible to think of extending that principle to properties other than "x is finite"? so we generalize it to some line properties, so for a property $P$ in that line, we stipulate that:

*any predicate $Q$ that is closed over the pure $P$ world, would generalize over the whole set world,*

or even stronger:

*any predicate $Q$ that is proximity closed over the pure $P$ world, would generalize over the whole set world*

Of course in both cases $Q$ must be expressible by a formula strictly shorter than the shortest expression defining property $P$, and also we stipulate parallel axioms sufficient to define the property $P$, also axioms asserting the element-hood of all hereditarily $P$ classes, and the existence of a set of all hereditarily $P$ sets. Of course this can only be done for some selected line of properties.

is that possible or it is involved with clear inconsistencies? and what would be the general qualification of such property $P$?

**After-note:** I have shorter definitions of finiteness and of subnumerousity, than the ones given here, those are:

Define: class $B$ is subnumerous to class $A$ if and only if:

$$\exists F \large{(} 
\normalsize \forall b [b \in B \to \exists a \exists f (a \in A \wedge f \in F \wedge b \in f \wedge a \in f \wedge \forall x (x \in f \to x=a \lor x=b))] \wedge
\forall a [a \in A \to \exists z \forall m (m \in F \wedge a \in m \to m=z)] \large {)}$$

I think this can be further shortened to:

$$ \exists F [\forall b (b \in B \to \exists a (a \in A \wedge \exists f (f \in F \wedge a \in f \wedge b \in f) \wedge \forall x  (\exists f (f \in F \wedge a \in f \wedge x \in f\wedge x \in B) \to x=b)))]$$

Define: class $a$ is said to be $finite$ iff:
\begin{align}
\forall k [&\exists m (m \in k)\\
&\land \forall x \forall y (x \in a \lor y \in k \to \forall z (\forall n (n \in z \to n=x \lor n \in y ) \to z \in k)) \\
& \to a \in k]
\end{align}

Comment: Your definition doesn't seem to include the empty set as finite. Also, you say that you think your definition is the shortest way to define "finite" in the first-order language of set theory, but your definition is not in the first-order language of set theory, but rather in the second-order language of set theory, since you are using class quantifiers.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the matter about the empty set being finite.about the language it is a first order axiomatic theory, the class quantifiers won't make the underlying logic second order logic, there is no quantification over function symbols nor over predicates, i.e. there is not quantifier that quantifies over all subsets of the universe of discourse, so it is formulated in FIRST order logic. The Classes are "elements" of the universe of discourse of this theory, and the quantifiers only quantify over those. Much as Morse-Kelley class theory

Comment: In the established terminology, the "first-order language of set theory" usually (i.e. basically always) refers to the language with only $\in$ and all quantifiers range over sets; and the "second-order language of set theory" refers to the languages where one also allows class quantifiers. For example, ZFC is a theory in the first-order language of set theory, and GBC and KM are stated in the second-order language of set theory. The fact that one may regard models of GBC and KM as first-order (two-sorted) structures is beside the point, since one can do this with any second-order structure.

Comment: “Shortest formula defining finiteness” is sensitive to both the language and the background theory.  It looks like your language has a constant (null set), a unary function (singleton), a binary function (union), a unary relation (set), and a binary relation (element) — is that the right signature?  And are you looking for the shortest formula defining finiteness in MK or in some other theory?

Comment: By the way, there is a standard convention in second-order set theory (and second-order logic generally) to use lower-case letters to quantify over the first-order objects and upper-case letters to quantify over the second-order objects. Thus, in set theory, $\forall x$ means for all sets $x$ and $\forall X$ means for all classes $X$.

Comment: @Matt F.44 no the only primitives are membership and equality and I mean finiteness in this theory

Comment: @joel iknow the stuff related to the naming I know it is confusing but still its first order axiomatic theory I know it is called second order language of set theory but I'm not speaking in that sense

Comment: But why not use the well-developed and widely understood theories, which seem fully capable of expressing the ideas you are trying to convey, instead of developing your own idiosyncratic notation and axioms? It seems to me that your questions would find a much better reception if you did so.

Comment: MK is a "first order axiomatic theory", this *is* the traditional description about it, MK is an extension of FIRST ORDER LOGIC, but you was right regarding me being wrong when I said "first order language of set theory" since this do have a different connotation, since the language of MK is 'termed' as "second order language of set theory" but this is just a matter of terminology MK is still a "first order axiomatic set theory", see this wikipedia on MK (second line) for example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory, anyhow I've corrected this error of mine

Comment: Yes, any second-order theory can be deemed as a first-order theory, by considering the second-order part to be added explicitly as objects. But to my way of thinking, to do this is to abandon a useful distinction. For this reason, I find the one-sorted approaches to KM to be unhelpful, a distraction. In my experience, the experts who are currently seriously studying the various second-order set theories (and I know them; I myself have several papers analyzing this hierarchy) are careful to observe the first-order/second-order distinction.

Comment: Given the 23 changes to the question, with some edits explicitly designed to reject a proposed answer, I will wait to see if this survives beyond the bounty period; if so, I will vote to close as unclear what you’re asking.

Comment: Question: How do you prove a transitive closure exists without using something like the axiom of infinity?

Comment: @ we have $V$ being a transitive superclass of any class in this theory, now the minimal transitive superclass can be proved from class comprehension.

Comment: the ternary principle was already mentioned there, "before the answer", but I've just made it more conspicuous by the further edit, the other edits are either typos or are in response to technical comments of Joel, which I've fixed. so most of these edits are actually fixing minor issues or highlighting something that already had been written. the main subject of the posting is still the same.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's OK for the transitive closure to be a class rather than a set in this context. Thanks, I didn't realize that.

Comment: @Zuhair: an important part of asking a question is listening to the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your transfer principle contradicts the axiom of foundation.

To see this, observe that under foundation, every nonempty finite set $x$ has an $\in$-maximal element, a set $z\in
x$ with $z\notin u$ for any $u\in x$, since one can simply climb up via $\in$ inside $x$ until one
reaches a maximal element.

But not every infinite set is like that, since the set
HF of hereditarily finite sets itself, for example, has no
$\in$-maximal elements.

Using this idea, we can produce a counterexample to your transfer principles under foundation. Let $\phi(y,x)$ assert that $x$ is not empty and
if $x$ has an $\in$-maximal element, then $y\in x$. This can be
expressed by a comparatively short formula. Namely, let $\phi(y,x)$ be the assertion $$(\exists z\
z\in x)\wedge[(\exists z\in x\ \forall u\in x\ z\notin u)\to y\in x].$$

If $x\in\text{HF}$ and $\phi(y,x)$, then $x$ is not empty and $y\in
x$, since every nonempty element of $\text{HF}$ has $\in$-maximal
elements. But there are sets $x$ in $V$ which are not empty, but
have no $\in$-maximal elements, such as $x=\omega+\omega$, and in
this case $\phi(y,x)$ holds for all $y$, including the case where $y$ is a proper class.

So this violates your transfer principles.

Comment: No this won't affect this method since not every x that fulfills $\phi(x)$ is finite for example take the set $\omega$ union the triple singleton of $\empty$

Comment: Ah, I understand a bit better, I think. Let me modify the example.

Comment: I posted a modified example, which I think is what you want.

Comment: This answer works by using not a definition of finiteness, but rather a necessary property of all finite sets that is not necessary for all sets. And the point is that there is a such a property (having an $\in$-maximal element) that is expressible by a short formula, so that the overall formula is still short.

Comment: Also wrong, but I generally think it can be modified to reach into your goals. The error is that not every non empty set in HF has a maximal element in the sense you've defined, but I think this can be salvaged really, and I think a modification of your argument would work. I'll look into it.

Comment: Every nonempty HF set has a $\in$-maximal element, since otherwise, you could keep going up in $\in$ inside the set, and get infinitely many elements that way.

Comment: what about a Quine atom?

Comment: Ah, you don't have foundation. In that case, you can modify the formula simply to say that $x$ is nonempty and well-founded, rather than just nonempty (and this is easily expressed). This in effect moves to the well-founded part of your set-theoretic universe.

Comment: "easily" expressed? perhaps, I'm not sure, but I thought it means that every non empty subset of the transitive closure of x must have an element that is disjoint of it. This takes more than 8 atomic formulas, and you already have five in the above formula, a total of more than 13, so it is about the length of the shortest definition of finiteness.

Comment: Yes, it seems unfortunately that your transfer principle applies to very few formulas of interest.

Comment: They might be few, but they are substantial, actually they are the formulas that can interpret the constructive axioms of the standard set theory ZF [union, power, separation, replacement], what else one would want really [perhaps infinity, but this is built-in it is what the transfer is all about, so its axiomatization is part of the background idea, so its justification "i.e. of infinity" is already "built-in" this line of thought]. However, I'm myself still suspicious of my own transfer principles, the chances are high that an inconsistency is there, but I don't know how, thus the question.

Comment: Well, I've already shown that they contradict foundation, which is something that many people would want. And I would think you would mention GB or KM rather than ZF, since the whole point of your project is to have classes as objects.

Comment: I think I can re-write this principle in the first-order language of set theory [in the usual sense]. The whole point is the TRANSFER principle and not to have classes as objects, this later piece is a just a tool to exposit that principle

Comment: foundation is not a big problem, it can be interpreted anyway from those axioms.

Comment: Try to see it the other way. IF there no inconsistency involved with it [I myself greatly doubt that], then it would provide a motivation for ZF axioms that doesn't rely on foundation, actually it relies on ANTI-FOUNDATION.

Comment: But without classes, then every $y$ is in $V$, so I don't really follow your remarks about not needing classes.

Comment: I mean you can define a pure set theory (I mean a theory without classes, like ZF, NF, etc..) and you can add to it a modification of the transfer principle above, and also you can prove from it separation, replacement, union and power, however the approach would be more complex.

Comment: your answer as it stands is wrong, so it needs to be corrected! by adding that foundation is assumed, or otherwise fix it by some other approach

Comment: OK, I have edited to mention foundation.

Comment: by the way I think your answer doesn't touch the ternary transfer principle. I've edited the post to explicitly mention this principle. Actually I think the ternary transfer principle is consistent relative to ZFC

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: I admire your patience!

Comment: The answer did show something, that foundation is dismissed by this method! I still think it can be salvaged by upgrading the principle to include transfer from the pure countable world as well. I'll make a rewrite at a separate post to exposit that in a better manner