# What is the shortest expression of finiteness?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

What is the shortest definition of "$x$ is a finite class" that can be formulated in the class theory presented at:

[Is it possible to derive the rules of set theory as transfers from the pure finite set world, and can we extend this further?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298927/is-it-possible-to-derive-the-rules-of-set-theory-as-transfers-from-the-pure-fini)

Here shortness is measured by the total number of occurrences of atomic formulas in the formula.

Some constraints are that:

- the formula must not use any defined symbol
- the logical primitives are the customary four logical connectives and the two quantifier symbols
- the language is MONO-SORTED FIRST order logic with the extra-logical primitives of identity and membership
- the axioms are the first 5 axioms of that theory and the identity axioms and the logical axioms

In other words we are looking for that equivalence in the hereditarily finite sector of mono-sorted first order Morse-Kelley $\text{MK}$ class theory.

For instance, the following formula contains only 8 occurrences of atomic sub-formulas and may be optimal:

A class $a$ is *finite* if and only if:

\begin{align}
\forall k [&\exists m (m \in k)\\
&\land \forall x \forall y (x \in a \lor y \in k \to \forall z (\forall n (n \in z \to n=x \lor n \in y ) \to z \in k)) \\
& \to a \in k]
\end{align}

**After-note:** now that Matt F. had written the following formula which is SHORTER than the above formula for finiteness, then the question would be whether there is a shorter formula of finiteness than that?

$$\neg\exists y (\exists z (z \in y) \mathbin\& \forall a (a \in y \to \exists b (b \in y \mathbin\& b \neq a \mathbin\& \forall c (c \in a \to c \in b\mathbin\& c \in x))))$$

An even shorter formula comporized of only 6 atomic formulas had been presented by Emil Jeřábek, that is:

$$\neg\exists y\,(x\in y\land\forall a\in y\,\exists b\in y\,b\subsetneq a)$$
where $b\subsetneq a$ expands to: $b\ne a\land\forall c\,(c\in b\to c\in a)$.

Comment: What is the advantage of minimising this count?

Comment: In general, we cannot usually prove directly that a given formula is the shortest to provably have a certain property, since if your underlying theory is inconsistent, then any formula is provably equivalent to finiteness.  So a solution here will need to make consistency assumptions.

Comment: @LSpice, my direct purpose was to use it in the transfer principle from the pure finite world in the theory I've referred to, but possibly it might have other uses that I'm not aware of

Comment: A search for minimal examples is common in research mathematics, eg the latest Polymath project.  Harvey Friedman asks questions like this about set theory too; it is not everyone’s taste in research mathematics, but I think it clearly qualifies.

Comment: You need to be more precise about what it means to "define finiteness."  Is it what some fragment of ZFC proves equivalent to the standard definition of finiteness?  Or do you mean to fix some model containing $V_\omega$ and ask about formulas in one free variable that apply to all and only members of $V_\omega$ in that model?

Comment: I was very precise, it is what THE THEORY with the first 5 axioms that I've referred to in the link proves to be equivalent to the standard definition of finiteness. I already said that explicitly.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, the fragment of the theory I've referred to, that is axiomatized by the first 5 axioms, is a conservative extension of $PA$, and I think there is much confidence in the consistency of such a theory.

Comment: So one way to do this would be brute force. List every formula shorter than the one you have, and see if you can find a proof or disproof that it applies exactly to HF things. You could automate this to search the proofs of length less than some N and then try to figure out any leftovers. Finding counterexamples to rule things out shouldn’t be too hard.

Comment: @MonroeEskew is that feasible? I mean using "brute force' by automated methods, I mean we have 8 atomic subformulas, with two kinds of atomic subformulas and 4 connectives and 2 quantifiers, etc.. that in addition to the axioms (which I believe we can render them finite if we change class comprehension to predicative version like the one in NBG), I thought the number of combinations would be so high, higher than the capability of any automated machine?

Comment: Are there any methods for similar problems?  Has anyone ever studied how to prove $\phi(x)$ is the shortest among all formulas $\psi(x)$ that theory $T$ proves $\forall x (\phi(x) \leftrightarrow \psi(x))$?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, see Friedman at https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3158348 on short formulas of set theory.  E.g.:  He proves that all 3-quantifier sentences are settled by ZF.  He conjectures that all 4-quantifier sentences are settled by ZF.  But (details at http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.135.5971&rep=rep1&type=pdf) there is an independent 5-quantifier sentence, equivalent to the existence of a subtle cardinal.

Comment: With only 7 atomic formulas, you can define “x is infinite” in ZFC as “there is a non-empty family of subsets of x, where none of those subsets are maximal in the family.”  Maybe it works for weaker theories too:  $$\exists y \exists z (z \in y) \& \forall a (a \in y) \to \exists b (b \in y \ \& \ b \neq a) \& \forall c (c \in a \to c \in b\ \& \ c \in x)$$

Comment: @MattF., I think the definition you've mentioned works!

Comment: Don’t you want a definition of hereditarily finite though?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, for the purposes of the transfer principles, if there is a definition of "hereditarily finite" that is SHORTER than the shortest definition of "finite", then yes this would be demanded, but I think the definition of the Hereditarily finite would be longer than the definition of the finite.

Comment: With input from Matt F. the question seems to have become more interesting and I am voting to reopen.

Comment: 6 atomic formulas suffice: $\neg\exists y\,(x\in y\land\forall a\in y\,\exists b\in y\,b\subsetneq a)$, where $b\subsetneq a$ expands to $b\ne a\land\forall c\,(c\in b\to c\in a)$.

Comment: I would also vote to reopen, were the question formulated for some standard set theory rather than an ad hoc system.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek the finite sector of MK is not an ad hoc system.

Comment: @EmilJerabek, nice formula, I have deleted my incorrect objection.

Comment: given the six atomic formulas of Emil, this would leave us with a check for 5 atomic sub-formula length, I think this can be done by brute force.